# Use liblinear on big data for semantic analysis

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, libsvm

I use [Libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) to train data and predict classification on **semantic analysis** problem. But it has a **performance** issue on large-scale data, because semantic analysis concerns ***n-dimension*** problem.

Last year, [Liblinear](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) was release, and it can solve performance bottleneck.
But it cost too much **memory**. Is **MapReduce** the only way to solve semantic analysis problem on big data? Or are there any other methods that can improve memory bottleneck on **Liblinear**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that there is an early version of LIBLINEAR ported to [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org). See [mailing list comments](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-LIBLINEAR-td5546.html) for some early details, and the [project site](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/distributed-liblinear/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like different from SVM. I'll survey it. :)

Comment: Just a reminder that we don't encourage linking off-site to an answer because its easy for links to break, causing an otherwise useful community resource to instead turn into a dead end. It's always best to put the answer directly into your post.

Comment: Agree with that. At this point, it barely exists as more than that link anyhow. I will add a link to the underlying project.

Answer (score 10):

You can check out [vowpal wabbit](http://hunch.net/~vw/). It is quite popular for large-scale learning and includes parallel provisions.

From their website:

> VW is the essence of speed in machine learning, able to learn from terafeature datasets with ease. Via parallel learning, it can exceed the throughput of any single machine network interface when doing linear learning, a first amongst learning algorithms.

Comment: Open source and some wiki. It looks good. Thanks for your suggestion. :)